# How to use ggplot with Haven dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-haven

New to coding and R but have a STATA dataset, I want to use ggplot for visulations of my data however, I get multiple errors such as

no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class `"c('haven_labelled', 'vctrs_vctr', 'double')"`

I dont know how to convert them so I can plot them for visualisations,

the lines of code are as followed:

```
Data <- read_dta("longitudinal_td.dta")


Data <- Data %>%
  select(pidp,wave,age_dv,sex_dv,ethn_dv,sf1_dv,bmi_dv,sf12pcs_dv,fihhmnnet1_dv,sf12mcs_dv) %>%
  filter(wave == "1", age_dv<=50)%>%
  mutate(pipd = row_number(),age=age_dv, sex=sex_dv, ethnicity = ethn_dv, general_health=sf1_dv,
        bmi=bmi_dv, physical_component_score=sf12pcs_dv, mental_component_score=sf12mcs_dv, household_income=fihhmnnet1_dv)%>%
select(-pipd,-age_dv,-sex_dv,-ethn_dv,-sf1_dv,-bmi_dv,-sf12pcs_dv,-sf12mcs_dv,-fihhmnnet1_dv)
```

I hope this is correct, here is the dput:

Essentially im just trying to explore BMI but i dont know if I can just plot these or have to assign the numbers to a label like it already is done in haven labels

```
dput(head(Data))
structure(list(pidp = structure(c(68001367, 68006127, 68008167, 
68009527, 68010207, 68010887), label = "cross-wave person identifier (public release)", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    wave = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "interview wave", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    age = structure(c(39, 39, 38, 31, 24, 45), label = "Age, derived from dob_dv and intdat_dv", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    sex = structure(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), label = "Sex, derived", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(Male = 1, 
    Female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), ethnicity = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "Ethnic group (derived from multiple sources)", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`white uk` = 1, 
    irish = 2, `gypsy or irish traveller` = 3, `any other white background` = 4, 
    `white and black caribbean` = 5, `white and black african` = 6, 
    `white and asian` = 7, `any other mixed background` = 8, 
    indian = 9, pakistani = 10, bangladeshi = 11, chinese = 12, 
    `any other asian background` = 13, caribbean = 14, african = 15, 
    `any other black background` = 16, arab = 17, `any other ethnic group` = 97
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    general_health = structure(c(2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1), label = "General health", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(excellent = 1, 
    `very good` = 2, good = 3, fair = 4, `or Poor?` = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), bmi = structure(c(29.6, 38.8, 21.5, 
    24.2, 25, 25.5), label = "Body Mass Index", format.stata = "%12.0g")
```

Comment: It is easier to respond if you post an example of your data with `dput(head(data))` and also the code that generates the error. Having said that, the class `c('haven_labelled', 'vctrs_vctr', 'double')` would seem to indicate a factor (i.e. categorical) variable, usually represented as text but stored in Stata as integer factor levels from 1 to n levels (as type `Numeric (long)`). So it doesn't make sense to rescale it.

Comment: Hi, I linked a picture of the R script, sorry i am new to all this and trying to figure out stuff. Basically I need to create visualisations with these variables and want to use the labels for plotting as they are all correctly assigned, however i dont know if thats possible, ty

Comment: What would help would be a small reproducible sample of data as copy/pasteable text, not a picture. We can't test code on a picture or debug a picture. Please don't post pictures of code. Please do use `dput()` as SamR suggests, `dput(head(Data))` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 6 rows. Perhaps include only a few sample columns that you want to plot, `dput(head(Data[c("pidp", "wave", "age_dv")]))` for example.

Comment: Yes I agree with @GregorThomas we only need a few columns. I can't see anywhere in the code you posted that you use the `rescale()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting an example of your data with `dput()`. The format of the data you have posted suggests that it has somehow become a list rather than a data frame. You need to convert it to a data frame - as you're using `haven` I would stick with the `tidyverse` and do it with `as_tibble()`.

Similarly, you want the labels rather than the underlying integers. You can simply apply [`as_factor`](https://haven.tidyverse.org/articles/semantics.html) to the whole data frame to do this.

Your data is then ready to be piped to `ggplot2`. For example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(haven)


Data  |> 
    as_tibble()   |>
    as_factor()  |>
    ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=sex, y=bmi))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try, thanks for being patient i'm learning as i go haha.

Comment: @DavidPeters no problem - let me know if it works with your real data

Comment: Hi again sorry, im being a complete noob but do i first save my datas as a dataframe such as  Data_1 <-as_tibble(Data) and then simply save the whole thing as as.factor? or do i do it individually for each variable... if that makes sense? (Basically im not sure how to proceed...)

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste the code I wrote. If not, `as_tibble()` and `as_factor()` can both be applied to data frames, not just individual columns. They both have comprehensive documentation which is worth reading.

Comment: I copied the code and like you did it printed a box plot, will I be able to max bar charts,scatterplots etc aswell?  Thanks

Comment: Yes - I thought the question was about how to read Stata data in R using haven. If you are asking about how to use ggplot2, best to start with the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: sorry, yes it was primarily, im just wondering do I have to specify Data  |> 
    as_tibble()   |>
    as_factor()  |>
    ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=sex, y=bmi)) before any sort of plot or

Comment: You need to do all those things except you can remove `geom_boxplot()` and replace it with the type of plot you want.

Comment: thank you just tried it and it worked!

Comment: Ok feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Hi, once again sorry to bother but I am stuck and would wonder if you happen to know the answer... Basically I want to group BMI into groups such as 18.5 or under as "Underweight" , between 18,5-24.9 as "Healthy Weight",  25-29 as "Overweight" 30-39 as "Obese" and 40+ as "Morbidly Obese" would you know how to do this?

Comment: Check out `case_when`